# Showing $\sigma(\tau(p))=(\sigma\tau)(p)$ for $\sigma, \tau\in\mathscr{S}_n$ and polynomial $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is Exercise 2.4.10 of F. M. Goodman's *"Algebra: Abstract and Concrete"*. I have found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682256/abstract-algebra-for-a-polynomial-p-prove-sigma-taup-sigma-taup).

> **Exercise 2.4.10:** Let $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be variables. For any polynomail $p$ in $n$ variables and for $\sigma\in\mathscr{S}_n$, define $$\sigma(p)(x_1,\dots,x_n)=p(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots, x_{\sigma(n)}).$$ Check that $\sigma(\tau(p))=(\sigma\tau)(p)$ for all $\sigma, \tau\in\mathscr{S}_n$.

### My Attempt:

I have
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(\tau(p))(x_1, \dots, x_n)&=\tau(p)(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)}) \\
&=p(x_{\tau(\sigma(1))}, \dots, x_{\tau(\sigma(n))}) \\
&=p(x_{(\tau\sigma)(1)}, \dots, x_{(\tau\sigma)(n)}) \\
&\color{red}{=(\tau\sigma)(p)(x_1,\dots, x_n)}
\end{align}$$ but then $\color{red}{\sigma(\tau(p))=(\tau\sigma)(p)}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality is wrong. You first have to apply $\tau$ and then $\sigma$:

$$ \sigma(\tau(p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)))=\sigma(p(x_{\tau(1)},\ldots,x_{\tau(n)}))=p(x_{\sigma(\tau(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma(\tau(n))})=(\sigma \circ \tau)(p(x_1,\ldots,x_n))
$$

$\textbf{Edit}$ I have just seen that you linked a question in which it is written in the way I wrote it, so it seems you have a slight trouble reading the definition (?). Write $P:=p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{\underline{\alpha}} a_{\underline{\alpha}} x_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots x_n^{\alpha_n}$, where $\underline{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ denotes a multi-index. Then, by definition, for $\sigma\in S_n$,
$$
\sigma(P):=\sum_{\underline{\alpha}} a_{\underline{\alpha}} x_{\sigma(1)}^{\alpha_1}\ldots x_{\sigma(n)}^{\alpha_n}.
$$

Comment: I thought I was applying $\tau$ first but, yes, I see where I went wrong. Thank you.